# API REST SYMFONY TWIG - AUTH

Tags: php, rest, symfony, twig

I'm working on a REST api with symfony, this will perform tasks related to users, authenticate, list, view details, create, etc.

I have already obtained the authentication but I have doubts, mainly with the TWIG views, since I want to centralize these views and not have to maintain them in each system that connects.

What I want to centralize is:

- View of user detail.
- View of create / edit user.

Is it okay to place these views in the API? Is it okay to return a full view from the API?
How should I do it? Since it is returned in JSON format

I am extending from FOSRestController.

Comment: You'll have do decide whether an API client is consuming HTML (for which you can use TWIG) or JSON (for which in my point of view the client is responsible how to display anything)

Answer (score 0):

You can make an action which will return JSON or HTML format depending od parameter, so for example you can use JSON format in mobile app and HTML format in some web app.

The possible solution is:

```
public function userDetailAction($id, $format)
{
    ...
    ...

    if ($format == 'json') {
        $response = new Response(json_encode($data));
        return $response;
    }

    return $this->render('userDetail.twig', array('userData' => $data));
}
```

or simpler json syntax in Symfony 3

```
...
if ($format == 'json') {
    return $this->json($data);
}
...
```

Comment: I understand, but what would have to change the "extends" the controller?

I am extending from FOSRestController.

Comment: In terms of controller - nothing.
You have those methods - setFormat, set Template etc. Just use them and You will be fine. Just look into docs: http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSRestBundle/2-the-view-layer.html

Comment: @Vini It worked, thank you very much, I'll comment below how I implemented it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @vini comment, I implemented it as follows:

```
...
$view = View::create(array('user' => $user))
          ->setTemplate("EdcorpUserBundle:User:advance.profile.html.twig")
          ->setFormat('html');

return $this->handleView($view);
}
```

ref: http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSRestBundle/2-the-view-layer.html